# How to initialize jquery plugins after append div on my web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using jquery mmenu on my web page. There two different kind menu used on this page. One for desktop another one for mobile. I'm not interested to duplicate the menu on this page. How can i call run jquery mmenu after append element. Below i have added my code.

```
<header class="clearfix">
        <a href="#mobile_menu">Menu</a>
        <!-- For desktop -->
        <div class="fR">
            <nav id="mainNav" class="fL">
                <ul class="clearfix">
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                        <ul class="clearfix">
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <!-- For mobile-->
        <div id="mobile_menu"></div>
    </header>
```

jquery,

Here i have used jquery mmenu (URL:http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/)

```
$(function() {
    $('body').wrapInner('<div id="main-container" />');
    $('#mainNav ul').clone().appendTo($('div#mobile_menu'));
    $('div#mobile_menu').mmenu();
});
```

Comment: just a question is it possible to just have the 1 menu, and use media queries for styling the different menu on mobile vs desktop?

Comment: No. But, i want to use mmenu plugin. Because i need to add 5 sub level menu on my page.

Answer (score 0):

```
Initalize jquery under

$( document ).ready( function() {


}
option because it load after page ready 
like 

$(document).ready( function() {

  $('body').wrapInner('<div id="main-container" />');
  $('#mainNav ul').clone().appendTo($('div#mobile_menu'));
  $('div#mobile_menu').mmenu();

}
```